# Append querystring to Parent page when we close the popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to append querystring to parent page when we close the popup window using javascript.
I am using below code but its not working :

```
parent.location.href =parent.location.href+"?PostComments=true";
```

Comment: `window.opener.location.search = "?PostComments=true";`

Comment: getting value of window.opener as undefined. Not working...

Comment: try `window.opener.document.location.search` ?

Comment: No luck. the querystring is not appending to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me! A bit too much to add to a comment, so I'll post it as an answer:

```
var win=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    win.focus();
    win.onunload = function() {
        window.location.search = "querystring"
    };
```

Note that once you change the querystring the page reloads, and the popup is opened again etc. in a loop, but I'm assuming you're opening the popup on some event and not on page load, so that should'nt be an issue really.